# How to request data from google analytics multi-channel funnels

Tags: node.js, google-analytics

I can successfully request data from the google analytics core reporting api but am struggling to pull from the multi-channel funnels api. I am pretty sure my problem is with permission/access but I've gone through the documentation and can't figure out exactly what the problem is. I am using node and the googleapis library. Here is my code for pulling the google analytics information (This works)

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var key = require('./auth.json');
var viewID = 'XXXXXXX'; 
var analytics = google.analyticsreporting('v4');
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email,
                                    null,
                                    key.private_key,
                                    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
                                    null);
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('Yup, we got authorized!');
    console.log(tokens)
  }
});
  var req = {
    reportRequests: [{
      viewId: viewID,
      dateRanges: [{
        startDate: '2020-11-01',
        endDate: '2020-11-01'}],
      metrics: [{expression: 'ga:pageViews'}],
      dimensions: [{name: 'ga:city'}],
      pageSize: 10
    }],
  };
  analytics.reports.batchGet({
    auth: jwtClient,
    resource: req
  },
  function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Failed to get Report');
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(response.data)
  }
);
```

This produces the desired output just fine. I tried to change the metrics and dimensions so I can pull some multi-channel funnel information that I want but am getting an error

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var key = require('./auth.json');
var viewID = 'XXXXXXX'; 
var analytics = google.analyticsreporting('v4');
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email,
                                    null,
                                    key.private_key,
                                    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
                                    null);
jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('Yup, we got authorized!');
    console.log(tokens)
  }
});
  var req = {
    reportRequests: [{
      viewId: viewID,
      dateRanges: [{
        startDate: '2020-11-01',
        endDate: '2020-11-01'}],
      metrics: [{expression: 'mcf:sourceMedium'}],
      dimensions: [{name: 'mcf:lastInteractionConversions'}],
      pageSize: 10
    }],
  };
  analytics.reports.batchGet({
    auth: jwtClient,
    resource: req
  },
  function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Failed to get Report');
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Success - got something back from the Googlez');
    console.log(response.data)
  }
);
```

It is producing this

```
 code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Unknown dimensions(s): mcf:lastInteractionConversions, unknown metric(s): mcf:sourceMedium\n' +
        'For details see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ]
```

I am pretty sure my problem is either I am requesting from the wrong source or my permissions are only available for ga and not mcf, but I don't fully understand the reason for the error or how to fix it, and the documentation hasn't provided much help. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using *Reporting API V4* instead of **Multi-Channel Funnels API V3**: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference

The API you need provides a single method to request data:

```
analytics.data.mcf.get()
```